# Filter grid from outside devexpress mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I have Devexpress DropDownEdit control over Grid. One of the grids columns is "Status" and it has five values from enumeration. DropDownEdit should filter grid columns by status and if I save Grid Layout data, selected values in dropdownedit should be saved too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recommendations from [this](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q364944) thread to learn more on how to implement the GridView "external filter".

P.S. Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding your issue?

Comment: I imagine it's because the devexpress support is mostly just "look at this random topic that won't actually show you how to do it, kthxbye".